# How do the below two packages vary according to usage?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree

**What is the difference between in using them for importing as packages both of them contains ElementTree.py program in the library**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
from elementtree import ElementTree as etree
```

If i replace one with other it shows an error, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xml.etree.ElementTree` is part of the Python standard library since Python 2.5: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html.

For `from elementtree import ElementTree as etree` to work, you have to install ElementTree separately. This was once necessary if you needed to use the library with older versions of Python (see http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm). With Python 2.7, there is no reason to do this.

So forget about `elementtree.ElementTree` and use only `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Comment: But my piece of code works with elementtree.ElementTree only so i will continue using it!!  Thanks for the information understood the difference!

Comment: If you create a new question and show us your piece of code, we can probably help with switching to `xml.etree.ElementTree`. It seems unlikely that you must use `elementtree.ElementTree`.

Comment: Okay no problem brother, If i found any further problem regarding switching the package i will ask it.