# Removing some elements in xml using element tree and appending elements from other xml file

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree, file-handling

**XML file1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:cim="http://iec.ch/TC57/2008/CIM-schema-cim13#"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<cim:ConnectivityNode rdf:ID="S1_CN1">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name>Connectivity Node 1</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
<cim:ConductingEquipment.Terminals rdf:resource="#S1_T1" />
</cim:ConnectivityNode>

<cim:BusbarSection rdf:ID="S2_BB2">
<cim:IdentifiedObect.name>Busbar Section S2_BB2</cim:IdentifiedObect.name>
<cim:Equipment.MemberOf_EquipmentContaiber rdf:resource="#S2" />
</cim:BusbarSection>
</rdf:RDF>
```

**XML file2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:cim="http://iec.ch/TC57/2008/CIM-schema-cim13#"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<cim:Substation rdf:ID="S1">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name>1000kV/13800kV</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
</cim:Substation>
</rdf:RDF>
```

My main aim is to actually remove the complete tree under specific parent by searching attribute of parent node( `like cim:ConnectivityNode`), add the child of `rdf:Rdf` from `xml file 2` to the `xml1` as  one of the child of it's root `rdf:Rdf` . Is this possible?

**Edit1: code that I tried**

```
from elementtree import ElementTree as etree
from IECcimextract import*
tree= etree.parse(r'N:/myinternwork/files xml of bus systems/temp.xml')
root= tree.getroot()
cim= "{http://iec.ch/TC57/2008/CIM-schema-cim13#}" #namespace uri for cim
rdf= "{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}" #namespace uri for rdf
tree2bus2break=etree.parse(r'N:/myinternwork/files xml of bus systems/9busi_in_61850.xml')
rootdbdb=tree2bus2break.getroot()
def convfun():
    for child in root:
        if (child.attrib['{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}ID'])[0]+(child.attrib['{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}ID'])[1]==S1:
            root.remove(child)

 convfun()
 tree.write("N:/myinternwork/files xml of bus systems/temp.xml")
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<ns1:BusbarSection rdf:ID="S2_BB2" xmlns:ns1="http://iec.ch/TC57/2008/CIM-schema-cim13#">>
<ns1:IdentifiedObect.name>Busbar Section S2_BB2</cim:IdentifiedObect.name>
<ns1:Equipment.MemberOf_EquipmentContaiber rdf:resource="#S2" />
</ns1:BusbarSection>
</rdf:RDF>
```

why does namespace cim isn't there in output?

actually I reduced the code to pin-point it, there are many parent-child tree with attribute value starting with S1,I used the same code there it removes only some of the child tree starting with S1 attribute value but not all of them . why is this happening?

thanks in advance

**Update 1, a query regarding the comment made by mzjn**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<country name="Liechtenstein">
<rank>1</rank>
<year>2008</year>
</country>
</data>
```

now run this python code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
tree= etree.parse(r'N:/myinternwork/files xml of bus systems/note.xml')
root= tree.getroot()
print root
```

It showing none, but where as if I import as

```
from elementtree import ElementTree as etree
```

It isn't throwing any error! what's the reason?

Comment: Btw, why don't you use the ElementTree module that comes with Python 2.7? `from elementtree import ElementTree as etree` is likely to confuse people. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44275848/407651.

Comment: If I use the xml.elementtree.etree then it isn't able to get the root of the xml , but with the package I used its fine .That is the reason I am using that brother!! Thanks for the answer it's working!

Comment: I have added a update showing a new code to show that it is giving none although I am using `getroot()` brother

Comment: You should post a separate question for the getroot problem (which I cannot reproduce btw). And if the IOError is out of the way, please remove everything related to that. It is not relevant anymore.

Comment: Do u mean to remove the part of the question which I have asked regarding the `Io error` ? If I do that Then your comment will not be relevant ri8?

Comment: The IOError has been taken care of, hasn't it? It is not relevant to the main problem of removing and adding elements. A good question should be possible to understand without reading the comments.

Comment: okay I edited the question now, Is it okay @mzjn thanks for your time for guiding me in edits for easy understanding!

Comment: In the question, there is no code that attempts to remove or add elements. What did you try? Where are you stuck? What exactly is the expected result?

Comment: I was stuck in implementing the Xinlcude for getting my result, I have edited the question again and pinpointed the expected result brother.